# Closest Ruby representation of a 'private static final' and 'public static final' class variable in Java?

Tags: java, ruby, static, private, public

Given the Java code below, what's the closest you could represent these two `static final` variables in a Ruby class? And, is it possible in Ruby to distinguish between `private static` and `public static` variables as there is in Java?

```
public class DeviceController
{
  ...
  private static final Device myPrivateDevice = Device.getDevice("mydevice");
  public static final Device myPublicDevice = Device.getDevice("mydevice");
  ...
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
   ...
  }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK there is no real constants(final) in Ruby

Comment: but one can use `SOME_CONSTANT.freeze` to make an object immutable

Comment: How about this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/18168745/665967

Answer (score 45, accepted):

There really is no equivalent construct in Ruby.

However, it looks like you are making one of the classic porting mistakes: you have a *solution* in language A and try to translate that into language B, when what you really should do is figure out the *problem* and then figure out how to solve it in language B.

I can't really be sure what the problem is you are trying to solve from that small codesnippet, but here is *one* possible idea for how to implement it in Ruby:

```
class DeviceController
  class << self
    def my_public_device;  @my_public_device  ||= Device['mydevice'] end

    private

    def my_private_device; @my_private_device ||= Device['mydevice'] end
  end
end
```

Here's another:

```
class DeviceController
  @my_public_device  ||= Device['mydevice']
  @my_private_device ||= Device['mydevice']

  class << self
    attr_reader :my_public_device, :my_private_device
    private :my_private_device
  end
end
```

(The difference is that the first example is lazy, it only initializes the instance variable when the corresponding attribute reader is first called. The second one initializes them as soon as the class body is executed, even if they are never needed, just like the Java version does.)

Let's go over some of the concepts here.

In Ruby, as in every other "proper" (for various definitions of "proper") object-oriented language, state (instance variables, fields, properties, slots, attributes, whatever you want to call them) is *always* private. There is *no way* to access them from the outside. The only way to communicate with an object is by sending it messages.

[Note: Whenever I write something like "no way", "always", "the only way" etc., it actually no means "no way, except for reflection". In this particular case, there is `Object#instance_variable_set`, for example.]

In other words: in Ruby, variables are always private, the only way to access them is via a getter and/or setter method, or, as they are called in Ruby, an attribute reader and/or writer.

Now, I keep writing about *instance variables*, but in the Java example we have *static fields*, i.e. *class* variables. Well, in Ruby, unlike Java, classes are objects, too. They are instances of the `Class` class and so, just like any other object, they can have instance variables. So, in Ruby, the equivalent to a class variable is really just a standard instance variable which belongs to an object which just happens to be a class.

(There are also class hierarchy variables, denoted with a double at sign `@@sigil`. Those are really weird, and you should probably just ignore them. Class hierarchy variables are shared across the entire class hierarchy, i.e. the class they belong to, all its subclasses and their subclasses and their subclasses ... and also all instances of all of those classes. Actually, they are more like global variables than class variables. They should really be called `$$var` instead of `@@var`, since they are much more closely related to global variables than instance variables. They are not entirely useless but only very rarely useful.)

So, we have covered the "field" part (Java field == Ruby instance variable), we have covered the "public" and "private" parts (in Ruby, instance variables are always private, if you want to make them public, use a public getter/setter method) and we have covered the "static" part (Java static field == Ruby class instance variable). What about the "final" part?

In Java, "final" is just a funny way of spelling "const", which the designers avoided because the `const` keyword in languages like C and C++ is subtly broken and they didn't want to confuse people. Ruby *does* have constants (denoted by starting with a capital letter). Unfortunately, they are not really constant, because trying to modify them, while generating a warning, actually works. So, they are more of a convention than a compiler-enforced rule. However, the more important restriction of constants is that they are always public.

So, constants are almost perfect: they cannot be modified (well, they *shouldn't* be modified), i.e. they are `final`, they belong to a class (or module), i.e. they are `static`. But they are always `public`, so unfortunately they cannot be used to model `private static final` fields.

And this is exactly the point where thinking about problems instead of solutions comes in. What is it that you want? You want state that

1. belongs to a class,
2. can only be read not written,
3. is only initialized once and
4. can be either private or public.

You can achieve all of that, but in a completely different way than in Java:

1. class instance variable
2. don't provide a setter method, only a getter
3. use Ruby's `||=` compound assignment to assign only once
4. getter method

The only thing you have to worry about, is that you don't assign to `@my_public_device` anywhere, or better yet, don't access it at all. Always use the getter method.

Yes, this *is* a hole in the implementation. Ruby is often called a "grown-up's language" or a "consenting adults language", which means that instead of having the compiler enforce certain things, you just put them in the documentation and simply trust that your fellow developers have learned that touching other people's privates is rude ...

---

A totally *different* approach to privacy is the one used in functional languages: use closures. Closures are blocks of code that close over their lexical environment, even after that lexical environment has gone out of scope. This method of implementing private state is very popular in Scheme, but has recently also been popularized by Douglas Crockford et al. for JavaScript. Here's an example in Ruby:

```
class DeviceController
  class << self
    my_public_device, my_private_device = Device['mydevice'], Device['mydevice']

    define_method :my_public_device  do my_public_device  end
    define_method :my_private_device do my_private_device end

    private :my_private_device
  end # <- here the variables fall out of scope and can never be accessed again
end
```

Note the subtle but important difference to the versions at the top of my answer: the lack of the `@` sigil. Here, we are creating *local* variables, not *instance* variables. As soon as the class body ends, those local variables fall out of scope and can never be accessed ever again. *Only* the two blocks which define the two getter methods still have access to them, because they close over the class body. Now, they are *really* private *and* they are `final`, because the only thing in the entire program which still has access to them is a pure *getter* method.

This is probably not idiomatic Ruby, but for anyone with a Lisp or JavaScript background it should be clear enough. It is also very elegant.

Comment: Great answer! In the final example, using *||=* seems redundant, and simple assignment should be sufficent?

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I can think of to a final variable is to put the variable in question as an instance variable of a module:

```
class Device
    # Some static method to obtain the device
    def self.get_device(dev_name)
        # Need to return something that is always the same for the same argument
        dev_name
    end
end

module FinalDevice
    def get_device
        # Store the device as an instance variable of this module...
        # The instance variable is not directly available to a class that
        # includes this module.
        @fin ||= Device.get_device(:my_device).freeze
    end
end

class Foo
    include FinalDevice
    def initialize
        # Creating an instance variable here to demonstrate that an
        # instance of Foo cannot see the instance variable in FinalDevice,
        # but it can still see its own instance variables (of course).
        @my_instance_var = 1
    end
end

p Foo.new

p (Foo.new.get_device == Foo.new.get_device)
```

This outputs:

```
#<Foo:0xb78a74f8 @my_instance_var=1>
true
```

The trick here is that by encapsulating the device into a module, you can only access the device through that module.  From the class `Foo`, there's no way to modify *which* device you're accessing, without directly acting upon the `Device` class or the `FinalDevice` module.  The `freeze` call in `FinalDevice` may or may not be appropriate, depending on your needs.

If you want to make a public and private accessor, you can modify `Foo` like this:

```
class Foo
    include FinalDevice

    def initialize
        @my_instance_var = 1
    end

    def get_device_public
        get_device
    end

    private
    def get_device_private
        get_device
    end

    private :get_device
end
```

In which case you'll probably need to modify `FinalDevice::get_device` to take an argument as well.

Update: @banister has pointed out that `@fin` as declared in `FinalDevice` is indeed accessible by an instance of `Foo`.  I had lazily assumed that since it wasn't in the default text output by `Foo#inspect`, it wasn't inside `Foo`.

You can remedy this by more explicitly making `@fin` an instance variable of the `FinalDevice` module:

```
class Device
    def self.get_device(dev_name)
        dev_name
    end
end

module FinalDevice
    def get_device
        FinalDevice::_get_device
    end

    protected
    def self._get_device
        @fin ||= Device.get_device(:my_device).freeze
    end
end

class Foo
    include FinalDevice

    def get_device_public
        get_device
    end

    def change_fin
        @fin = 6
        @@fin = 8
    end

    private
    def get_device_private
        get_device
    end

    private :get_device
end

f = Foo.new
x = f.get_device_public
f.change_fin
puts("fin was #{x}, now it is #{f.get_device_public}")
```

Which correctly outputs:

```
fin was my_device, now it is my_device
```

Comment: +1, very elegant. Also, thanks for inspiring my closure-based solution!

Comment: what do you mean the ivar isn't directly available in the class? if you define a method on Foo such as `def change_fin; @fin = 100; end` and then run `f = Foo.new; f.change_fin; f.get_device_public` the return will be 100. You can simply access @fin in the class and it changes _exactly_ the same @fin that's defined in the module. An object has only one ivar table.

Comment: @banister: you were right; I've updated the code to explicitly use an instance variable of the `FinalDevice` module.  I had lazily assumed that since `@fin` didn't show up in `p Foo.new` that it was already contained in the `FinalDevice` module.  But now it's obvious that it just hadn't been declared yet.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
class DeviceController
  MY_DEVICE = Device.get_device("mydevice")
end
```

And yeah, `require 'device'` if needed.

Although nothing will stop you from redefining the constant somewhere else, except a warning :)

Comment: actually it *is* public :) you can do DeviceController::MY_DEVICE from all the places in your program. Not sure how to make it private though.

Comment: private constants have been talked about for Ruby 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

private static in Ruby:

```
class DeviceController
    @@my_device = Device.get_device("mydevice")
end
```

public static in Ruby:

```
class DeviceController       
    def self.my_device; @@my_device; end

    @@my_device = Device.get_device("mydevice")
end
```

Ruby can have no 'final' :)