# Ruby and Inheritance

Tags: ruby, class, inheritance

I'm trying to understand inheritance:

```
class Car
  @@wheels = 4
  def wheel
    @@wheels
  end
end

class StretchLimo < Car
  @@wheels = 6
  def whee
    @@wheels
  end
  def turn_on_television
  end
end
```

I instantiate some objects like so:

```
moe = Car.new
larry = StretchLimo.new
```

When I do `moe.wheel`, I get `6`, when I'm expecting `4`.

The Ruby tutorial I'm following says it's supposed to be `4`.  `Larry.whee` should obviously return `6`.

By the way, the "`wheel`" and "`whee`" functions I added so I could see the values. Can anyone explain what's wrong here?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please format your code properly.

Comment: class variables in ruby are strange and confusing. it's probably easiest to not use them.

Answer (score 1):

Class variables in Ruby are [strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2084490/ruby-class-variables) and [confusing](http://www.oreillynet.com/ruby/blog/2007/01/nubygems_dont_use_class_variab_1.html).

An idiomatic way to implement what you want is this:

```
class Car
  def wheels
    4
  end
end

class StretchLimo < Car
  def wheels
    6
  end
end

Car.new.wheels #=> 4
StretchLimo.new.wheels #=> 6
```

Whats happening is that class variables are *shared* between all instances of a class. Because `StrechLimo` is a subclass of `Car` instances of `StrechLimo` also see this variable.

Comment: this is almost certainly not the preferred method...see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441524/closest-ruby-representation-of-a-private-static-final-and-public-static-final

Answer (score 0):

`@@` is a class variable so it is shared across all objects instantiated from a given class and all derived class. Because Ruby is interpreted, until you instantiate a `StretchLimo` object, it should not look at any of the `StretchLimo` code, so if you did the following:

```
moe = Car.new
moe.wheel # should give 4
larry = StretchLimo.new
moe.wheel # should give 6
```

Because when the `StretchLimo` gets interpreted it updates the `@@wheels` class variable to be `6`. On the other hand, if you declared "wheels" with only one "`@`" (`@wheels`), it would be an instance variable specific to the object itself, and you would get your preferred behavior.

Comment: this is not actually true. `moe.wheel` gives 6 on the second line. try it.

Comment: depends on directory structure and how interpreted. I do get moe.wheel -> 6 if both classes are defined in the same file and I load from there, but this is not the case if I force the interpreter to load these classes sequentially. Regardless, the preferred method is to use instance variables